# map,lambda and append.. why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to do this.

```
a = []
map(lambda x: a.append(x),(i for i in range(1,5)))
```

I know map takes a function but so why doesn't it append to the list? Or is append not a function? 
However printing `a` results to `a` still being empty

now an interesting thing is this works

```
a = []

[a.append(i) for i in range(5)]
print(a)
```

aren't they basically "saying" the same thing?

It's almost as if that list comprehension became some sort of hybrid list-comprehension function thing

So why doesn't the lambda and map approach work?

Comment: what exactly are you doing?  I ran the first example and it populated list a.  It also returns another list with nulls, which makes sense.

Comment: @MK. what are you sure? I'm doing on idle and list `a` is empty what did you do?

Comment: No lambda is actually needed here; `a.append` is already a function that can be called to add `x` to `a`.

Comment: _a_ is populated - as a side effect, which is usually a bad idea. The result of list comprehension is _list_ of _None_ - since _list.append_ returns _None_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Python 3.x , the actual reason why your code with map() does not work is because in Python 3.x , map() returns a generator object , unless you iterate over the generator object returned by map() , the lambda function is not called . Try doing list(map(...)) , and you should see a getting filled.

That being said , what you are doing does not make much sense , you can just use -

```
a = list(range(5))
```

Comment: there you go. that's what I was looking for now it works if you make it a list. and yes although. It doesn't make any sense I was trying to test my understanding of lambdas. it's just the concept that I wanted to test really. and yes like everyone else said. it doesn't make sense. but I guess I understand a bit more about lambdas now.. thank you though

Answer (score 5):

`append()` returns `None` so it doesn't make sense using that in conjunction with `map` function. A simple `for` loop would suffice:

```
a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append(i)
print a
```

Alternatively if you want to use list comprehensions / map function;

```
a = range(5) # Python 2.x
a = list(range(5)) # Python 3.x
a = [i for i in range(5)]
a = map(lambda i: i, range(5)) # Python 2.x
a = list(map(lambda i: i, range(5))) # Python 3.x
```

---

```
[a.append(i) for i in range(5)]
```

The above code does the appending too, however it also creates a list of `None` values as the size of `range(5)` which is totally a waste of memory.

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a.append(i) for i in range(5)]
>>> print a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print b
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: or just _a.extend(range(5))_

Comment: @ozgur yeah this one was pretty simple however. it's not that I want a populated list rather why isn't it getting populated. using lambda. because map takes an iterable and a function and runs all of those iterables to a function and so shouldn't list `a` be populated? doing that approach regardless of it making sense to do so or not

Comment: @volcano it's not about extending the list hehe. I more puzzled as to why it doesn't work. when map takes a function and iterable and applies all the iterables to the function. so why doesn't a get populated?

Comment: @Zion, unlike Python 2.7, `map` and `range` functions return a generator object in Python 3 so you have to force evaluating them using `list()`.

Comment: @ozgur I know cursed lazy evaluation! haha but yeah. I'm still clawing and scratching to understand  all these heaps of concepts because well I'm a total noob. but yeah thanks for taking the time to answer and school me. I really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1):

The functions map and filter have as first argument a function reference that is called for each element in the sequence (list, tuple, etc.) provided as second argument AND the result of this call is used to create the resulting list

The function reduce has as first argument a function reference that is called for first 2 elems in the sequence provided as second argument AND the result is used together with the third elem in another call, then the result is used with the fourth elem, and so on. A single value results in the end.

```
>>> map(lambda e: e+10, [i for i in range(5)])
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> filter(lambda e: e%2, [i for i in range(5)])
[1, 3]
>>> reduce(lambda e1, e2: e1+e2, [i for i in range(5)])
10
```

Explanations:

- map example: adds 10 to each elem of list [0,1,2,3,4]
- filter example: keeps only elems that are odd of list [0,1,2,3,4]
- reduce example: add first 2 elems of list [0,1,2,3,4], then the result and the third elem of list, then the result and fourth elem, and so on.

Comment: your filter function is really cool. because at first I was like. shouldn't it return all the even values? but then I remembered that  filter returns `truthy` things and all the numbers `%` 2 that equals to zero wouldn't be included because zeroes are `falsey` so that's pretty neat

Answer (score 1):

This `map` doesn't work because the `append()` method returns `None` and not a list:

```
>>> a = []
>>> type(a.append(1))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

To keep it functional why not use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) instead?

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda p, x: p+[x], (i for i in range(5)), [])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function will not get triggered unless you wrap the call to map function in list() like below

```
list(map(lambda x: a.append(x),(i for i in range(1,5))))
```

map only returns a generator object which needs to be iterated in order to create a list. Above code will get the lambda called.

However this code does not make much sense considering what you are trying to achieve